# Comparing two strings in C (string pointers)

Tags: c

I have a string array that is declared like this:

```
    char * d[] = {"bca", "abc", "cba", "abcd"};
```

I'm trying to compare d[1] to d[2] in a generic compare method (using void *):

```
int compareString(void * p1, void *p2)
{
    char * s1 = (char *) p1;
    char * s2 = (char *) p2;
    while(*s1 && *s2)
    {
        if(*s1 > *s2) return 1;
        else if(*s2 > *s1) return -1;
        s1++;
            s2++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason when I try and print s1\s2 I get some gibberish.
Note: It does work if the array is declared like this:

```
char e[][5] = {"bca", "abc", "z", "dca", "cba"};
```

EDIT:

Code where I call the function:

```
void sort(void * arr, int arrLength, int sizeOfElement, int (*compare)(void *, void *))
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < arrLength; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < arrLength - 1; j++)
            if(compare(((char *)arr + j * sizeOfElement), ((char *)arr + (j + 1) * sizeOfElement)) > 0) swap(((char *)arr + j * sizeOfElement), ((char *)arr + (j + 1) * sizeOfElement), sizeOfElement);
}
```

And I look at s1 and s2 via the debugger.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you printing them? Show us that code too.

Comment: How are you *calling* this routine? Show that code as well.

Comment: @moooeeep if they are the same it goes on to the `s1++;` line which is the intended behaviour

Comment: What exactly are you comparing about these strings? Looks like it finds the first character that's different and then returns which one has the higher value?

Comment: For one, the logic is incorrect if you fed "ca" and "cat" to this function. Identical *prefix* of non-identical strings will report as equal; but they're not.

Comment: @JohnU that's the behaviour of the standard function `strcmp`

Comment: You're calling the `sort()` function incorrectly.

Comment: @MattMcNabb How exactly?

Comment: Let me fetch my crystal ball

Comment: @MattMcNabb, I don't think so, this function here returns `0` as soon as one of the strings is finished.

Comment: @JensGustedt I meant that it would not segfault or read off the end of the string (i.e. do "gibberish"), but have removed my comment for clarity

Comment: Your casts for the array are completely screwed.

Comment: @JensGustedt It works for 4 other tested array types. What's so different here?

Comment: This: `char * d[] = {"bca", "abc", "cba", "abcd"};` is an array of *pointers*, whereas this: `char e[][5] = {"bca", "abc", "z", "dca", "cba"};` is an array of **arrays**. They're *not* equivalent. The former will send the *addresses* of two *pointers* to your comparator. The latter will send the address of an array. That, assuming you actually send the right element sizes for each (which we don't know because you haven't shown us how you call this). You need two different comparator functions for this.

Comment: You still haven't bothered to show how you call `sort`, but assuming it is `sort(d, 4, sizeof d[0], compareString)` then you end up passing *pointers to pointers* into `compareString` but that function aliases them as if you had passed in *pointers to char*.

Comment: @MattMcNabb So how do I fix it?

Comment: `char * s1 = *(char **) p1; char * s2 = *(char **) p2;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For array 'e' this is the cmp:

```
    int cmpS1(void *aa,void *bb){
    int r;
    r=strcmp((char*)aa,(char*)bb);
    return r;
    }
```

And for array 'd' you need this cmp:

```
int cmpS2(void *aa,void *bb){
    char* s1=*(char**) aa; char* s2=*(char**) bb;
    while(*s1 && *s2){
        if(*s1 > *s2) return 1;
        else if(*s2 > *s1) return -1;
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```